# How make ScrollView Scroll to particular position android?

Tags: android, view, scroll, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm added child to linearlayout inside scrollview
linearlayout .addview(child);
inside for loop
then I want Scroll to any child I by code by postion or number

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollView.smoothScrollTo`. Let's say you are using `TextView` as a child of `linearLayout`, then you can do this:

```
val listItem = listOf<Item>()
val selectedIndex = 5
var selectedView: TextView? = null

listItem.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
    /*
        inflate your child layout here
    */
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parentLinearLayout, false)
    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title_text)

    if(index == selectedIndex){
        selectedView = textView
    } 
    parentLinearLayout.addView(textView)
}

scrollView.post {
    scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, selectedView.top)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is kotlin code to scroll to particular position of view added in scrollview(horizontal)

```
 horizontalScrollView.post {
    val targetView = findViewById<View>(R.id.target_view)
    val targetX = targetView.left
    horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(targetX, 0)
    }
```

for vertical scroll just change **`targetView.left`** to  **`targetView.top`**

for **JAVA** here is a sample code:

```
scrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int targetViewY = targetView.getTop();
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, targetViewY);
    }
}, 500);
```